# Are custom HTML attributes not using the data-* prefix valid?

Tags: html, angularjs

AngularJS gives the option of, but does not use the data- prefix in their examples or mandate the use of it. Should I include the data- prefix in my project and why?

Is it still valid HTML if I don't use data-*?

Comment: Not a constructive question but an opinion poll. To make the question constructive, you should present the question more clearly (what exactly are you using) and specify the criteria to be applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Many libraries like knockout, angular etc. do not use the data- prefix.

Knockout [uses data-*](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html): "`<span data-bind="text: myMessage">`"

Angular [uses data-*](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive): "the directive can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant" (shame they don't understand that it is for compliance with HTML and not with the validator).

> Should i include the data- prefix ?

Yes, you should write valid HTML. If you are making up attributes, use `data-` ones.

Comment: Why the big ones ignores valid HTML ?

Comment: They probably don't care, but until you become one of them - use the data attributes.