# Are custom HTML attributes without data- prefix a valid attribute?

Tags: html, markup

I recently found [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). I noticed that they use custom attribute prefix `ng-`.

From articles like [this one](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) or
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091848/2803917) the only *valid* (I'm not talking about the fact that they work anyway) prefix to use is `data-`.

How can it be that these million projects and companies use an invalid prefix for custom HTML element attributes?

Comment: Honestly though, what other answer is there? Custom attributes that don't have the data-* prefix are non-standard, after all.

Comment: They're not "Not valid" they're just not standard.

Answer (score 45):

This is an old question, but the following may be helpful.

In principle, you can create any attributes you want, though you can’t expect the browser to know what to do with them. This is true both in HTML:

```
<p thing="whatever" … </p>
```

and in JavaScript

```
//  p = some element
p.setAttribute('thing','whatever');
```

You *can* expect CSS to take your custom attribute seriously, as long as you use the attribute selector:

```
…[thing] {
    …
}
```

Of course, if you start making up your own attributes, you run into three problems:

- An HTML validator won’t know whether your new attribute is deliberate or an error, and will assume that it’s incorrect
- You are competing with other code which is also making up its own attributes
- At some point in the future it’s possible that your made-up attribute name becomes a real-life attribute, which would cause further problems

The `data-` attribute prefix has three benefits:

- HTML validators will ignore the attribute for validation purposes
- JavaScript will gather these attributes into a special `data` object for easy access
- You don’t run the risk of competing with real attribute names

Effectively the `data-` prefix allows you to work with an otherwise invalid attribute by telling the validator to overlook it.

This will not solve the problem of competing attribute names, so you’re pretty much on your own. However it is common practice to at least include a prefix specific to a library.

Finally to the question of being **valid**.

If, by **valid**, you mean will it pass a standard (modern) HTML validator, the answer, is only the `data-` attributes will work this way. If, on the other hand, you mean will it work, then both CSS and JavaScript will happily work with other made up attributes, as long as you don’t expect the browser to guess what you mean.

Comment: Just one question arises, If that's the case - HTML validator does not like this idea - and I guess it was also possible for Angular dev team to use good venerable `data-*` attribute but they did not. Why? Any fact/reference?

Comment: @KasirBarati I don’t use Angular myself, but they did run into the same problem. From Wikipedia: _“Since __ng-\*__ attributes are not valid in HTML specifications, __data-ng-\*__ can also be used as a prefix. For example, both __ng-app__ and __data-ng-app__ are valid in AngularJS.”_ If you’re not running your code through a validator, it doesn’t matter what attribute names you use, but to be safe, the `data-ng-` prefix is available.

Answer (score 8):

Custom attributes must start with data- or x- or they are invalid.
This might cause problems in future browsers, and HTML validators will say they're invalid.

See: [What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app)

And: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: So,  I'm right,  they are invalid,  after all,  right?

Comment: Please note that some js frameworks that use similar approach - e.g. Vue js using their "v-" attributes - dynamically remove these attributes (well, convert them into something useful) at page load before anything is shown by the browser, thus making the resulting html perfectly valid. I reckon Angular is doing the same. Browsers shouldn't really care about html that is not actively contained/displayed in the DOM.

Comment: I was unaware of the `x-` prefix. Is that for real?

Comment: @Manngo I don't think that there is a valid `x-` prefix. I couldn't find anything about this when searching for it. When I read this post, I assumed that the person posting mean that `x` is any arbitrary prefix that the W3C defines to be acceptable within a specification, such as `data-`. However, the wording implies that `x-` is a user defined attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Official [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) does not consider `ng-customattr` or `x-customattr` attributes, or `customattr` as valid.

Statement, that even `data-` prefixed custom attributes are invalid are false, check this [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

However it is worth to notice projects like Laravel's Dusk [encourage developers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk#interacting-with-elements) to use custom, non `data-` prefixed attributes.

It is worth noting, that official W3C specifications are not exclusive way how to build HTML page, but rather reccommended ones. I would dare to say, there are unspoken standards, which are widely used on web and yet tolerated by all the major browsers, even though they are not mentioned in w3c specifications. According to this [article](https://code-maven.com/custom-html-attributes), custom named html attributes are disregarded, but yet still accessible, therefore a viable option.

I afraid there is no firm ground below our feet - By naming your parameter prefixed by `data-`, you are doing things by reccomended way - avoiding possible deprecation warnings, or another issues, if browsers will be in future more strict. However standards can change, and since custom-way named attributes are widespread over the web, they can became standard themselves.

### So whats the solution?

If you really want to use custom, non `data-` prefixed attributes in `HTML`, it would be good to make a research about general browser support (Of find someone who already did this and published his research results in some article), and make your decision based on that - just like with any other HTML/CSS/JS feature.